# Is there an FLVPlayback onHttpError?

Tags: actionscript-3, flv, flvplayback

I'm able to tell if an *image* path was file-not-found or not, because I can attach to the loaders httpStatus. I can't find anything similar for an *FLV* (not using streaming).

EDIT - this is what I'm trying to do, although this code doesn't work:

```
flv.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
    if(event.status != 200){
        console.error("VIDEO httpStatusHandler.Error: " + event.status, event);

    }
}
flv.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    console.error("VIDEO ioErrorHandler: " + event);

}
```

I found my problem. I was doing:
flv.load(path)
flv.play()

By not waiting for some kind of status before calling play, I was squelching the connectionError status.

Comment: You may get more help if you tag the question "actionscript-3", as that's the tag everyone is using.
Also, can you add more details about what you are trying to do?

Comment: do you have a sample code for you problem? coz i didn't get your question